# How to return the last two lines of summary output from a linear model in R?

Tags: r, lm, summary, tail

After finding a regression prediction in lm I want to return only last two lines of the summary. What would be the best function to use?

```
my_model_lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = [data])
summary_result <- summary(my_model)
```

I want to return only:
Multiple R-squared:  [value],   Adjusted R-squared:  [value]
F-statistic:   [value] on [value] and [value] DF,  p-value: < [value]

I tried the `tail()` function, `cat()` function, `summary(my_model$)r.squared` at some basic level.
Was not able to return the desirable output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `capture.output` then select with `tail` and print with `cat`

```
cat(tail(capture.output(summary_result), 3))
```

A complete example:

```
> my_model <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt, data=mtcars)
> summary_result <- summary(my_model)
> cat(tail(capture.output(summary_result), 3))
Multiple R-squared:  0.8268,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8148  F-statistic: 69.21 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 9.109e-12
```

If you want to assign the output to a variable, then you can do:

```
>  output <- tail(capture.output(summary_result), 3)
```

Afterwards you can print it using `cat`

```
> cat(output) 
Multiple R-squared:  0.8268,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8148  F-statistic: 69.21 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 9.109e-12
```

Comment: When assigning the    `cat(tail(capture.output(summary_result), 3))`    to a variable it returns `NULL` at the end. Is there an alternative method that doesn't require installing of another package?

Comment: @Gwyrion see the update

Answer (score 2):

We can use broom like this:

```
library(broom)
model <- lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3, anscombe)

fmt <- "Multiple R-squared: = %f, Adjusted R-squared: %f, F-statistic: %f on %d and %d dof, p-value < %f"
with(glance(model),
  sprintf(fmt, r.squared, adj.r.squared, statistic, df, df.residual, p.value)
)

## [1] "Multiple R-squared: = 0.666542, Adjusted R-squared: 0.629492, F-statistic: 17.989943 on 1 and 9 dof, p-value < 0.002170"
```